# select button appears a dropdown with options where each is supposed to update state

Tags: reactjs

RangeDropdownButtons function returns a selectable button with a dropdown, where if you click each option it is supposed to update the state but unfortunately it does not update. What do you guys think might be causing the issue? I don't get any errors.

```js
this.state = {
  chartRange: 'All'
};

handleChange = (value) => {
  this.setState({chartRange: value})
}

RangeDropdownButtons = () => {
  return (
    <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
      <option value="All">All</option>
      <option value="lastWeek">7 Days</option>
      <option value="lastMonth">1 Month</option>
    </select>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the event to get the value, so change `value` to `e.target.value`.
Your function should then look like this

```
handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({chartRange: e.targe.value})
}
```